# Template nested class of template class as parameter to fully specialized function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator, c++17

I built a custom templated iterator as a nested class of a templated container:

```
template< typename T, class U, typename V >
class aContainer {
  public:
    template< bool ABool, bool BBool >
    class aIterator {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using referenc = T&;
        using pointer = T*;
       /** iterator related operations */
    };
  protected:
    T const * const _begin;
    T const * const _end;
  public:
    explicit aContainer( T const * const begin, std::size_t count ):
      __begin{ begin }, __end{ __begin + count } { }
    auto begin_a() const { return aIterator< true, false >{ __begin }; }
    auto end_a() const { return aIterator< true, false >{ __end }; }

    auto begin_b() const { return aIterator< false, true >{ __begin }; }
    auto end_b() const { return aIterator< false, true >{ __end }; }
};
```

To match the style of an existing library i want to pass a reference of the iterator to  a fully specialized templated function:

```
template< typename T, template< class > class U >
T max( T* data );

template<>
int max< int, aU >( int* data ) {
  return old_c_style_max_int( data, aU< T >::size );
}

template<>
float max< float, bU >( float* data ) {
  return old_c_style_max_float( data, bU< T >::size );
}
```

Maybe that looks a bit weird, but this shadows the different old-c-style function calls quite nicely.

Class U is a helper struct, creating a specific context (or flavour). The container and its iterator(s) need that context.

```
template< typename T >
class aU {
  using constexpr std::size_t size = 10;
  using value_t = T;
  /** ... */
};
template< typename T >
class bU {
  using constexpr std::size_t size = 20;
  using value_t = T;
  /** ... */
};
```

What I want to achieve is passing the iterator into the function as a parameter like that:

```
/* ... */
aContainer< int, aClass, bool > container( start );
auto iterator = container.begin_a();
for( ; iterator != container.end_a(); ++iterator ) {
  foo< int, aClass >( iterator );
}
/* ... */
```

Is this even possible? My guesses were rejected by the compiler :/
I think, a wrapper struct could be a possible solution, but I would like to avoid that. Also an iterator base class, shadowing the template iterator class seems feasible but not preferable from a conceptual point of view.

Comment: This is only possible if your specialized `foo` declares its parameter's type to exactly match the type of the iterator being passed in. I.e., the specialization is something along the lines of `template<> void foo< int, aClass >(aContainer<int, aClass, char *>::aIterator<true,false> param);`.

Comment: Yeah but that is exactly not what I want to do :D I mean, that way forces me to massive code duplications. Isn't there another nice c++17 hack? :D

Comment: Overloads are usually preferred to full specialization of template functions... to be honest, I don't really get why you want these functions to be full template specializations (maybe you could tell us why ?). Normally you'd have a `template<class T, class U, class V, bool A, bool B> void foo(typename aContainer<T, U, V>::template aIterator<A, B>)` generic template function and then overloads for each special case.

Comment: Aside note: identifiers containing a double underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Well, the functions wrapping the actual calls, depending on types deduced from a given template.

Comment: Please don't confuse subclasses with member types, they are quite different concepts.

Comment: You are totally right! I changed the text, to be correct! I am talking about nested classes not subclasses!

Answer (score 1):

You can add another type parameter to `foo`:

```
template<typename T, class U, typename Itr> void foo(Itr itr);
```

If you want to underline that `T`, `U` and iterator are coupled via `aContainer`...well, you'll still need an extra argument... a few extra arguments:

```
template<typename T, class U, bool flag, bool a, bool b> void foo(typename aContainer<T, U, flag>::template aIterator<a, b> itr);
```

But this time you'll need to give your compiler full information about the outer type, in other words, provide `flag` too (iterator's own parameters `a` and `b` will be deduced):

```
foo<int, aClass, true>( iterator );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hoped I could avoid that extra template parameter, because it is specified somewhere else. But auto specifier does not work with specialization as far as I know. So i guess, this will be an eligible way.